# Loop in R not functioning correctly

Tags: r

I have problems with my coded loop for some of my variables. I have run it firstly with one variable and it ran fine. Upon entering a different variable and different data range, the loop did not include all the outputs that it should have done according to the loop. There was no error message. The code for the loop is below:

```
geartype=data[179:187]
data_stats_structure_gt=as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=3))
names(data_stats_structure_gt)=c('Gear.Type','Man_Kendall_pvalue','Man_Kendall_tauv')

for (i in 1:ncol(geartype)){
  
  dat=geartype[,i]
  dat=as.data.frame(cbind(data$ï..Year,dat))
  ds=names(geartype)[i]
  names(dat)=c("Year",names(geartype)[i])
  dat=dat[-which(is.na(dat[,2])==TRUE),]
  if(nrow(dat)>=3){
    output=as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=3))
    names(output)=c('Gear.Type','Man_Kendall_pvalue','Man_Kendall_tauv')
    
    output$Gear.Type=names(geartype)[i]
    output$Man_Kendall_pvalue=mk.test(dat[,2])$p.value
    output$Man_Kendall_tauv=mk.test(dat[,2])$estimates[3]
    
    data_stats_structure_gt=rbind(data_stats_structure_gt,output)
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no output

Comment: @onyambu my output is the as.data.frame matrix, is this not correct? (R newbie)

Comment: Please use `dput(data[1:10, ] )`  to share the first ten rows of your data

Comment: @Ben Unfortunately I can't share the data however the dataset is not complete and with NAs i filled the NAs with 0 to see what happens and then the loop worked, but obviously i can't do that for the stats analysis. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Sorry Paula, but without any data it may be close to impossible to help out. Can you not obfuscate the data set and provide at least a sample of it that reproduces the problem (use `dput` or `dput(head())`)?